# Is Greedy Layer-Wise Training of Deep Networks necessary for successfully training or is stochastic gradient descent enough?

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoders, deep-belief-networks, pre-training

Is it possible to achieve state of the art results by using back-propagation only (without [pre-training](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/3048-greedy-layer-wise-training-of-deep-networks.pdf)) ?

Or is it so that **all** record breaking approaches use some form of pre-training ?

Is back-propagation alone good enough ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pre-training [is no longer necessary](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/22u1yt/is_deep_learning_basically_just_neural_networks/cgqgy9w). Its purpose was to find a good initialization for the network weights in order to facilitate convergence when a high number of layers were employed. Nowadays, we have [ReLU](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/proceedings/papers/v15/glorot11a/glorot11a.pdf), [dropout](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/dropout.pdf) and [batch normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167), all of which contribute to solve the problem of training deep neural networks. Quoting from the above linked reddit post (by the Galaxy Zoo Kaggle challenge winner):

> I would say that the “pre-training era”, which started around 2006, ended in the early ’10s when people started using rectified linear units (ReLUs), and later dropout, and discovered that pre-training was no longer beneficial for this type of networks.

From the ReLU paper (linked above):

> deep rectifier networks
>   can reach their best performance without
>   requiring any unsupervised pre-training

With that said, it is no longer **necessary**, but still may improve performance in some cases where there are too many unsupervised (unlabeled) samples, as seen in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6597.pdf).

Comment: This is a good answer but I think it would be even better if you could find an academic reference, rather than a Reddit thread.

Comment: Aren't the 3 above enough? It's even written in the abstract of the first one.

Comment: The revision is exactly the kind of support for the claim that "pre-training is no longer necessary" that I was hoping for. Thank you for contributing to our website.

Comment: Here is a related question : is pre-training doing the same as dropout (in some sense) ?

Comment: This answer is **very wrong**, or at best misleading; BN, Dropout, etc serve roles largely orthogonal to pretraining, where latter enables _transferable feature learning_. Example: denoising, dimensionality-reducing, missing-data reconstructing timeseries autoencoder's encoder placed at input prior to a classifier neural net; the classifier learns _discriminatory_ features, very distinct from that of the autoencoder.

Comment: I didn't say they do pretraining.